# How do you input the value of a radio button form with multiple input values as a string and input to the database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms, radio-button

So basically, i have this application form for A website and am trying to add radio buttons so people can select the correct answer from the given selection of options. I would also like to be able to input the value of the form into the database as a string, as say "HOME OWNER".

```
<%= form_for @applicant do |f| %>
```

The top "email" field works great. All actions are in place in the applicants_controller and the database is set up which means i can save the output from the email form field into the database. But the radio buttons don't work. Here below is in my views/applicants/new.html.erb

```
 <%= f.label :email %>
 <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

   <%= radio_button_tag(:property_relationship, "Home-Owner") %>
   <%= label_tag(:Home_owner, "Home Owner") %>

   <%= radio_button_tag(:property_relationship, "Private-Tennant") %>
   <%= label_tag(:private_tennant, "Private Tennant") %>

   <%= radio_button_tag(:property_relationship, "Landlord") %>
   <%= label_tag(:landlord, "Landlord") %>

   <%= radio_button_tag(:property_relationship, "Council-Tennant") %>
   <%= label_tag(:council_tenant, "Council Tennant") %>

   <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```

The below line is in my routes.rb file which makes the routing happen

```
resources :applicants
```

This is my applicants_controller.rb file

```
class ApplicantsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @applicant = Applicant.new
  end

  def create
      @applicant = Applicant.new(applicant_params)

      if @applicant.save

          flash[:success] = 'Form submitted'
          redirect_to apply_path
      else
          flash[:danger] = 'Error occured, message has not been sent'
          redirect_to apply_path
      end
  end

  private

      def applicant_params
          params.require(:applicant).permit(:property_relationship, :email)
      end


end
```

And my database schema.. the radio buttons in my form are to enter the "property_relationship" info from the form into the database. Is it maybe that it should be t.somethingelse instead of t.string?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160928204355) do

  create_table "applicants", force: :cascade do |t|

   t.string   "property_relationship"
   t.string   "email"
   t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end
```

I also have another table in the schema which is for a contact - which is below. But this shouldn't interfere as the form_for is for @applicant.

```
  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

This is the log/development.log file

```
Started POST "/applicants" for 88.106.10.152 at 2016-10-05 21:49:59 +0000
Processing by ApplicantsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UBXlJ5gzz+BEYk+SDgzSlR8AVctsLJkyKW51NhGbjTLf2tFzzuUvhJ5ahn2R/kCWBZVNRnl5DebP4GG0QxNKwA==", "property_relationship"=>"Home-Owner", "applicant"=>{"email"=>"daniel@example.com"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "applicants" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["email", "daniel@example.com"], ["created_at", "2016-10-05 21:49:59.209017"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-05 21:49:59.209017"]]
   (15.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to https://boilerleadgen-danthedangerman.c9users.io/apply
Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 16.5ms)


Started GET "/apply" for 88.106.10.152 at 2016-10-05 21:49:59 +0000
Processing by ApplicantsController#new as HTML
  Rendered applicants/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 89ms (Views: 87.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And here is the rails console using Applicant.all command. As you can see the value for property_relationship in nil but actually should be the value i entered (home owner)

```
(user_application) $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.3.0 :001 > Applicant.all
  Applicant Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "applicants".* FROM "applicants"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation #<Applicant id: 8, email: "daniel@example.com", property_relationship: nil, created_at: "2016-10-05 21:48:17", updated_at: "2016-10-05 21:48:17">
```

I am really stuck here and am also new to Rails so all help is much appreciated.
Once again, what i'm trying to do is save the output of the radio buttons into the database as a string.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. have a look in your server logs (either `log.development.log` or in your terminal window) and look at the lines that get printed just as you submit the form. They will usually display the full set of `params` that come through when you hit submit. Edit your question and post what you see there so we can see it and it will help us to debug your problem (don't post it in the comments here as the formatting is dreadful and hard to read) :)

Comment: Note: at present my best guess is that the radio-buttons are simply named incorrectly... you are using `radio_button_tag` instead of `f.radio_button` which means they probably won't be nested under `applicant` the way they should... we can confirm this by looking at what comes through in the `params`

Comment: I got it to work! i just needed to change radio_button_tag to f.radio_button thanks for that!

Comment: Cool, I'll make that an answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your radio-buttons are simply named incorrectly... you are using `radio_button_tag` instead of `f.radio_button` which means they probably won't be nested under `applicant` the way they should (and that your permit/require method is expecting).

You can confirm this by looking at what comes through as `params` in your server logs.